# Configuring JAVA project to use hadoop on different (virtual) machine

Tags: java, maven, hadoop

I have a maven project in Intellij Idea locally, and I want to set it up to use Hadoop that I installed on virtual machine. Any suggestions on that?

I have Windows 8.1 locally and Ubuntu 12.0.4 on virtual machine. I have already installed Hadoop there and its working.

EDIT:
Hadoop setup on VM:
core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

and mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

and hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

Network on my VM (vmware player) is NAT, and ip address is 192.168.35.128.

Then, I have a simple java project in Intellij Idea (dint think this is important but anyway...), and here is my configuration:

```
String hdfsUrl = "hdfs://192.168.36.128:54310";
FileSystem hdfs;
final Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.set(FS_DEFAULT_NAME, hdfsUrl);
 try {
            hdfs = FileSystem.get(config);
            if (hdfs != null) {
                hdfsAvailable = true;
            } else {
                throw new IOException("Unable to get hdfs, is NULL");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.warn(e.toString());
        }
```

and when I start it, I got the following error:

> java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: hdfs

so obviously I'm missing something. My OS is windows 8, and on VM is Ubuntu.

IMPORTANT EDIT No.2:

> telnet 192.168.36.128 54310

was successfull, but stil nothing from app...

Comment: Do you mean you want to simply connect to Hadoop to get data or you want to debug code you've written that's running in Hadoop?

Comment: Simply to connect for start.

Comment: AFAIK there is no plugin for IDEA to do that. But there exists an eclipse plugin if you want to use.

Comment: I will update question to be more understandable.

Comment: can you ssh the host without entering the password manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occures due to missing library **hadoop-hdfs-*.jar** in the classpath. For accessing HDFS file system, if you add hadoop-hdfs-*.jar alone won't solve this issue, need to following for dependencies.

```
hadoop-hdfs-*.jar
hadoop-common-*.jar
dependecy jars inside common/lib directory.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something which works from my eclipse (without any plugins).

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://name-node:8020");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(configuration);


    Path filePath = new Path(
            "hdfs://name-node:8020/user/test/000000_0");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error earlier. I was missing hadoop-hdfs jar from the classpath on the client. In your case the idea project is the hdfs client. "hdfs" scheme is defined in HdfsConstants.java which is packaged in hadoop-hdfs.jar. Since hdfs is reachable outside the project, missing classes is the most likely problem. Try adding hadoop-hdfs and hadoop-common to the build path.

I am assuming you are using hadoop 2.X

Answer (score 1):

Add the config files with Configuratuion objects

```
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
     conf.addResource(new Path("/path of file /core-site.xml"));
     conf.addResource(new Path("/path of file /hdfs-site.xml"));
```